# Access or MySQL in a big company

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access, intranet

Since a month, i'm working for a big company in France. They asked me to make a application manage their plannings. I devellopped something not so bad using their existant Access database and VB.net.
The problem is that in a few months, the application will maybe be used by 70 workers while today only 10 use it.
So i did a lot of researches, and i read that Access could not support more that 20 connection in the same time.
Firts, is that true ? What do I risk with an Access database for 70 workers ?
And then, what do you think of MySQL in my case ? The application won't be connect on internet, only on intranet. I took a very long time to connect my application to MySQL, but now i don't know how to connect the application in intranet.
In fact i'm a bit lost with the choice of my SGDB.

I'm sorry for my English and my bad explanations but i'm french and i didn't find the answers to my questions in french forums.

Thanks to those who will help me.

Comment: The Jet/ACE database engine can handle 70 simultaneous users, but it depends on what they are doing -- if they are all involved in heavy-duty editing/updating, you could have problems. I would upsize to a different back end in your case. MySQL is fine for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql can handle very large projects, it's stable, updated and free, so I think you shouldn't think to go on with Access.
Connecting to MySql will be quite easy: include MySql.Data.dll and change db connection string, it's easy and you'll find a lot of examples on internet.
If your app should only talk with db in intranet, simply install MySql on a server and connect your app using server ip and port.

Comment: First, I have to say that i'm really impressed by your very quick answers, which are really good. It's clear now, i have to forget Access. The only thing i'm affraid of is to create the connection on the server. I did it with Mysql server 5.5 on my computer, does it work similar ?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: @Ben: is exactly the same!! Install MySql on server, open port on firewall (if there's one) and use server ip in connection string: work completed!

Comment: Okok. Thank you very much, i'll do that right now. Thank you very much for your answers, they were so clear and really helped me. Plus that was really quick. (Sorry to respond on comment but i'm new on this forum and i can't respond by the normal way.)

Comment: @Ben: remember to vote and/or [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that best helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: Do i just need to put a tic in green to accept the answer ? (Thanks to your responses, i will now come to this forum and try to help the others as you helped me with my poor english.)

Comment: @Ben: yes, you've accepted my answer. Welcome to StackOverflow (SO), I hope you can help others as you've just helped! This phylosophy makes SO a great forum :)

Answer (score 3):

Please, use MySQL.

There is almost no excuse to use Access backend.

Like you said, Access has very poor connection abilities (every time the database is open, a connection is created as long as the program is still opened). Also, it has poor backup options (do you really want to make copies of the file every day?).

Also, Access has a "repair and compress database" option (for MDB, not sure about the newer format). It has a poor record of data consistency from what I experience with MDBs daily.

MySQL gives you a reliable data store, connections can be pooled properly, it has transaction support, and you can also run proper backups on it.

You can have a MySQL backend, and use Access forms as a frontend. I expect this should be a good enough compromise, and lets you scale it easily.

Comment: All the information in this post regarding Jet/ACE (not Access) is pretty much overstated. Downvoting accordingly. However, that said, with 70 users, I'd upsize the back end, too, even though I'm a professional Access developer and have no qualms whatsoever about using Jet/ACE as my data store.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen Access database have real poor security and which is terribly slow. If at all you intend to open your access database after a few days of running in production, you will see the how slow it can be.

Though it looks like you are new to MySQL, you will not need much of a learning curve to work with it. MySQL have lot of users that you will get a good support for you MySQL related questions also. And the best of all you will be able to learn MySQL, which i am sure you will use later for other applications you create.

Comment: Thank you for respond. I agree with the fact it's really slow. On my computer, i can the opening of the first form (which does about 15 sql  requests) is immediate, but when the 10 workers use it on intranet, they wait between 5 to 10 seconds before seeing it work. Plus, MySQL is not really new for me, I used it a school this year, but it was already installed on our computers, so that is the only thing i did not know how to do. I'll try this morning with the system administrator of the company.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the one that has to maintain the application also in future then drop the idea of Access and change into MySQL.
Access is only for personal use (or maybe with some small number of co-users)

Answer (score 0):

the number of users for your app shouldnt matter, u should use mysql simply because it's free. robust, can handle heavy traffic and very professional. it has pretty much clients for any programming language and there are tons of documentation in the internet.

 
i hope this will help